# Create date series between 2 dates in sas

Tags: loops, date, unix, sas

So I have a code as following:

```
%let mon_first=02Jan2018;
%let mon_last=02Mar2018;
%let start=%sysfunc(inputn(mon_first, Date9.), yymmn6.);
%let end=%sysfunc(inputn(mon_first, Date9.), yymmn6.);

%macro call(yrmon, yr, mon);
```

The macro named `%call`will perform certain tasks by taking into account months between mon_first and mon_last in yymn6. format.
Therefore, I have used the following loop:

```
%do i = &start. to &end.;
yrmon=put(i)
yr=substr(yrmon, 1,4);
mon=substr(yrmon,5,2);
%call(yrmon, yr, mon);
%end;
```

I get an error at `yrmon=put(i)` stating:`Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.`
Any suggestions here please?

Comment: You seem to be mixed macro syntax with normal data step code syntax.  Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an integer for the loop counter. Then use the integer with the `intnx()` to figure out the next month.

```
%let mon_first=02Jan2018;
%let mon_last=02Mar2018;
%do i=0 %to %sysfunc(intck(month,"&mon_first"d,"&mon_last"d));
  %let month=%sysfunc(intnx(month,"&mon_first"d,&i));
  %let yrmon=%sysfunc(putn(&month,yymmn6));
  %let yr=%sysfunc(year(&month),4);
  %let mon=%sysfunc(month(&month),z2);

...

%end;
```

Comment: ERROR: The %DO statement is not valid in open code -> I get this

Comment: If you want to use macro logic you need to create a macro to contain it and then call the macro. Your original code would also need to be inside of a macro definition.